# How to explore hadoop file with .job extention

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I have apache-nutch-2.3-SNAPSHOT.job file and I would like to explore what is packed inside. What tools should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Well I finaly found that *.job extension is similar to *.jar extention and so it can be simple unziped.

```
unzip myjob.job
```